# Set App icon without using Asset catalog in Xcode 7

Tags: swift, icons, assets, tvos

I'm developing tvOS application with Swift. And i need to set the app icon by image files in my Resources folder (**don't** use the *Asset catalog*).
i tried setting the key *CFBundleIcons* in *.plist* but it seems not working.

Is there any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to set the App Icon:

1. Use Asset Catalog
2. Use Asset Catalog

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/) for more requirements on these icons

Comment: So is there no way to set the app icon using image files ?
It's weird because i can set it successfully in my previous iOS project.